# GRE integral using residue

Tags: calculus, residue-calculus

I am supposed to evaluate the following integral:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(5x)}{1+(x-\frac{\pi}{2})^2} dx$$

So does this guy have a pole at $\frac{\pi}{2}$? I wanna try and use the Residue theorem to solve it but my complex analysis is a bit rusty. Any hints much appreciated!

Comment: What are the bounds of integration? Do you mean from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$?

Comment: ooh sorry good cacth!

Comment: The integrand has no poles on the real axis.

Comment: but does it on the Riemann sphere? it seems as tho this guy is defined on the Riemann sphere

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it does or not.  The integral makes sense as a real-valued integral, though you may be able to use complex analysis to evaluate it.

Comment: how would I integrate over the reals? by parts?

Comment: I'll show you.  $\space$

Comment: A minor simplification is to let $u=x-\pi/2$, so that the integral becomes $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos(5u)}{1+u^2}\,du.$ This makes it easy to see that the result will be nonzero.

Comment: ahh and you use the conversion between sin cos using $\frac{\pi}{2}$??

Comment: @HossienSahebjame you have provided the following link in other post, but I could not see this problem. I think it would be nice when you state the source of the problem, so other GRE takers (like me) can refer. THANKS A LOT :) https://www.math.ucla.edu/~bonsoon/summer2020/files/problems.pdf

Comment: @Hussain-Alqatari you asked about another problem, that other problem is on this link trust me lol

Comment: @HossienSahebjame May I know the problem number from that resource, please?

Comment: @HossienSahebjame I am still looking for the problem number in the link you provided. Kindly let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you want to use the residue theorem and you have trig functions, you'll generally want to be a bit clever and replace the trig functions with exponentials.

In this case, you're looking for the imaginary part of $\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{5ix}}{1 + (x - \pi / 2)^2} dx$.

We can consider the contour of a large semi-circle in the upper half-plane.

To determine where the function isn't holomorphic, we set its denominator $1 + (x - \pi/2)^2$ to zero. The function thus has simple poles at $\frac{\pi}{2} \pm i$. The only relevant pole here is at $\frac{\pi}{2} + i$, since the other pole is in the lower half-plane.

Computing the residue at this point gives us $\frac{e^{5i (\pi/2 + i)}}{2i} = \frac{i \cdot e^{-5}}{2i} = \frac{1}{2e^5}$.

So the integral with the complex exponential will be $2 \pi i \frac{1}{2e^5} = i \frac{\pi}{e^5}$. The imaginary part of this integral is $\frac{\pi}{e^5}$, which is the original integral.